# Change Visiblity and Change text for hidden Hyper Link from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this can be done using javascript but I need simplest way if there is any: I have gridview with following code  @aspx page

```
    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink  ID="idLinkBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TR") %>' </asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HyperLink  ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TR") %>' Visible="false"></asp:HyperLink>

<asp:HyperLink  ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TR") %>'  Visible="false" ></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

How can I access the hidden hyperlinks and set their text and make them visible from code behind? I tried  "Find control" method
but it is returning null value.
    Answers appreciated!

```
Thanks!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of GridView.

For example,

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      var idLinkBtn = e.Row.FindControl("idLinkBtn") as HyperLink;

      // The as operator will return null if the cast fails,
      // so check for null before you try to use the hyper link
      if(idLinkBtn != null)
      {
          idLinkBtn.Visible = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh,Man! I tried exact steps yesterday it gave me null value and it worked today! Anyways Thanx!

Comment: @user2801184 - when you tried it before did you check the `RowType` value for data rows only? If you do not check that, then it looks in the header row first, which probably does not have your `HyperLink` control.

Comment: @KarlAnderson: dr = mycommand.ExecuteReader();  while (dr.Read()) {GridView2.DataSource = dr;                                    GridView2.DataBind();} It does not call ROw dataBound method. I need to check every row of a column to determine if multiple Test numbers are present(1234,5678). And I wonder why is this happening?